# How do I tell the installer what my home directory is?

Tags: installation, make

Could someone please tell me how to tell the installer what my home directory is?

Comment: please specify the installer (what program are you trying to install) /??

Comment: by the way your home directory is /home/yourUserName or ~

Comment: thank you for the quick response! I have compiled the super nintendo emulator,bsnes.after running make,it compiled and then i tried running sudo make install.I believe the installer is g++-4.6

Comment: Where exactly do i set my home directory?

Comment: Your home directory is set in `/etc/passwd`. There's usually no reason to change it. Maybe you could write a little bit more about what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the bsnes .deb package here: http://www.playdeb.net/software/bsnes
It contains the latest version for Ubuntu 10.10, 11.04. 11.10 and 12.04. Install the right one for your system.